# Where should I insert PATH in .bash_profile?

Tags: linux, bash, path, virtualenv, pipenv

I tried to install `pipenv` and got warnings which suggest me to add a certain directory to PATH.

```
➜  ~ pip install --user pipenv
...
...
Installing collected packages: virtualenv-clone, pipenv
  WARNING: The script virtualenv-clone is installed in '/Users/mmiyazaki/Library/Python/3.6/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/Users/mmiyazaki/Library/Python/3.6/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pipenv-2018.11.26 virtualenv-clone-0.5.4
```

So I tried to edit `.bash_profile` like below but this file looks a bit unfamiliar to me. Is `.bash_profile` supposed to look like this or am I opening a different file? And for adding `export PATH="/Users/mmiyazaki/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH"` where should I insert `export PATH="/Users/mmiyazaki/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH"` in this file?

```
➜  ~ cat ~/.bash_profile
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/mmiyazaki/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/mmiyazaki/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/mmiyazaki/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/mmiyazaki/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Comment: Is there a reason, why you setup the PATH only if `conda.sh` does **not** exist?

Comment: I don't actually know. I didn't edit .bash_profile by myseld. When I opened it, it already looked like this.

Comment: You should care yourself about your dot-files, and at least sanitze them. I would find it creepy, if some installer commands secretly modify my carefully handcrafted dot-files.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I will investigate.